# Usage of commas in a non-restrictive clause

Tags: commas

I am wondering about the usage of commas in the following sentence.

> I have given, in English, multiple seminars.

I am not sure if nonrestrictive is the correct term, but I believe that "in English" is a nonrestrictive clause. If we remove "in English", the sentence simply becomes: "I have given multiple seminars.", which still makes sense. However, something still feels off about the given sentence.

Comment: It feels off because the normal order is *I have given multiple seminars in English.*

Comment: More idiomatic: "I have given multiple seminars in English" or "In English, I have given multiple seminars." Not sure if you are using the best test for whether your clause is restrictive or not.

Comment: The reason why I didn't write "I have given multiple seminars in English", is because I thought it sounded like I was giving a seminar about a topic related to the English language. However, I believe one gives a seminar ON a topic rather than IN a topic, so I was probably wrong in thinking there could be some ambiguity there.

Comment: @Kayle: Noting that Google Books thinks it has almost 500 hits for [*He lectured **in physics***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22he+lectured+in+physics%22) (as compared to just 344 for [*He lectured **on** physics,*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22he+lectured+on+physics%22)) I think you must accept that there's at least the *potential* for ambiguity, regardless of what preposition you use.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was hoping there was some way to completely avoid the ambiguity, but I guess if the use of both "in" and "on" is widespread, then the context of the sentence will have to suffice for the reader.